Why is error "OSError: GetModuleFileNameEx failed" generated in running scikit-learn k-nearest neighbours?
In using scikit's 'KNeighborsClassifier' (with n_neighbors = 3) and '.fit' to train, then using '.predict' to do multinomial classification I am getting the error message "OSError: GetModuleFileNameEx failed".
My code runs many times quite happliy through this loop, but then sometime generates the OSError, then crashes.
I'm using scikit-learn version: 1.3.0.
I was expecting the code to run to completion, which sometimes it does, which is great, but quite often it gives this error.
I tried using scikit-learn version: 1.2.0, but i have the same problem; sometimes it runs fine, but 50% of the time it gives this OSError. I use Anaconda as Python package manager.
many thanks, N.

I am getting this error as well, wondering if there is an update?
